# cannot find symbol error BufferedOutputStream(file.newOutputStream(CREATE))

Tags: java

Please help guys. I tried this code I read in a PDF about java programming ang encountered this

> error : cannot find symbol error
>   FileOut.java:16 : error: cannot find symbol
>           BufferedOutputStream(file.newOutputStream(CREATE));

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;

public class FileOut
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Path file = 
        Paths.get("C:\\Java\\Chapter.13\\Grades.txt");
        String s = "ABCDF";
        byte[] data = s.getBytes();
        OutputStream output = null;
        try{
            output = new 
            BufferedOutputStream(file.newOutputStream(CREATE));
            output.write(data);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Message: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you imported `java.io.*` package??

Comment: I believe the compiler is complaining about the constant named `CREATE`. You have not declared anything with this name.

Comment: Yes as @Code-Apprentice is saying where have you declared `CREATE`?

Comment: CREATE is define in java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption wich is static import

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`java.nio.file.Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) has no method named `newOutputStream()`.

This is what you should do instead:

```
output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file, CREATE));
```

Comment: You can probably remove the second choice, the code has `import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;`

Answer (score 0):

According to the Path [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), there doesnt exist any method named newOutputStream() . I think what you want to use is with [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

```
public static OutputStream newOutputStream(Path path,
                           OpenOption... options)
                                    throws IOException
```

> This method opens or creates a file in exactly the manner specified by
>   the newByteChannel method with the exception that the READ option may
>   not be present in the array of options. If no options are present then
>   this method works as if the CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, and WRITE
>   options are present. In other words, it opens the file for writing,
>   creating the file if it doesn't exist, or initially truncating an
>   existing regular-file to a size of 0 if it exists.